# C# - Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto

Tags: c#

Estou com esse erro no meu codigo:

```
 try
        {
            localhost.Agendamento a = new localhost.Agendamento();

            a.Cliente.Cpf = "1909009921";
            a.Servico.Cod_serv = 1;
            a.Data = Convert.ToDateTime("11/02/2017");
            a.Hora = Convert.ToDateTime("11:50");

            Service1 sv = new Service1();
            sv.CadastrarAgendamento(a);
            MessageBox.Show("Cadastrou!");
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.Message);
        }
```

O a exception ativa quando chega na linha

```
a.Cliente.Cpf = "1909009921";
```

A exceção que da é "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto"

Comment: Seu  objeto `Cliente` foi instaciado ? pode ser esse o problema ele esta tentando acessar `Cliente.cpf` enquanto `Cliente`  está `null`. tente debugar e verificar isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisa criar um objeto cliente em a.

```
a.Cliente = new CLiente();
```

Comment: Agora conseguir.

Answer (score 0):

O que pode estar acontecendo e que na hora que seu código tenta acessar `a.Cliente.Cpf` ele encontra o seu `Cliente` nulo, assim gerando esta exceção,  então você teria que instaciar seu objeto `Cliente`.

Faça o seguinte:

```
a.Cliente = new CLiente();
```

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado a todos que ajudaram eu consegui era só instanciar um objeto cliente e um objeto serviço dentro de Agendamento

```
a.Cliente = new CLiente();
a.Servico = new Servico();
```